# Bypassing the @Cacheable annotation in Production for debugging

Tags: java, spring, caching

I'm working on a new Spring based project and I was wondering, if i were to use the @Cacheable annotation found in Spring 3.1 or in the [ehcache-spring-annotation](http://code.google.com/p/ehcache-spring-annotations/) project, how would you go about implementing a mechanism for bypassing the cache mechanism "on demand", e.g. for production debugging.

Let's say my application serves only REST requests, on occasion, i would like, for a single call (that i manually make) to get data directly from the "DB" (or what ever backend there is) and avoid and any caching on the way (*any* caching). While the call is running, I don't really mind if it re-populates the cache with what it just got from the db...

I would like to hear your thoughts on how you would go about implementing this.

Thanks in advance for any guidance,

Ken.

Comment: Do you want to bypass the cache in a complete different environment, or just on demand with in the production environment without restart?

Comment: both actually. i want this mechanism to be useful in both the dev environment and the production environment. but its less critical in the dev env, since there i can simply restart the caches if i want to debug... in production i can't just restart them (as you said)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can extend the cache manager and provide a boolean expression in addition to the existing checks.

That boolean you can set in a `ThreadLocal` in your controller, so that whenever the service is invoked, the boolean is in place.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a method that flushes the cache and run it only with your debugger when you want a value from the DB.

```
@Cacheable(modelId = "i18NTextCacheModel")
public List<I18NText> loadAll() {

    logger.debug("loadAll called");
    ...
}

@CacheFlush(modelId = "i18NTextFlushModel")
public Long save(I18NText entity) {

    logger.debug("save called");
    ...
}
```

Comment: i think you've misunderstood me. lets say i have a getItem({...}) with a @Cachealbe annotation. I want the code to run normally, but when the methods with the annotation runs, i want to actually ignore the cache and go straight to the db..i don't want to manually run any method since i want to code to continue running normally.

Comment: If you flush your cache before the method with the annotation runs, that's exactly what will happen. You can write in the code - if(debug){//flush the cache}

Comment: you mean write this if(debug){//flush} into the annotation code itself? otherwise I don't see how i can control if the annotation runs or not..

Answer (score 0):

Arrived at a similar result as suggested by @Bozho
If the request parameter **refresh-cache=true** is passed, the cache gets bypassed

I extended DefaultRedisCacheWriter and used it as the CacheWriter

```
    RedisCacheManager cacheManager = RedisCacheManager
            .builder(new RefreshableRedisCacheWriter(redisConnectionFactory()))
            .cacheDefaults(cacheConfiguration)
            .build();
```

Overwrite the get() method in this writer

```
@Override
public byte[] get(String name, byte[] key) {

    Assert.notNull(name, "Name must not be null!");
    Assert.notNull(key, "Key must not be null!");

    HttpServletRequest request = ApiRequestContext.getRequestContext();
    if (Boolean.valueOf(request.getParameter("refresh-cache"))) {
        logger.info("bypassing cache for key: {}", key);
        return null;
    }

    return execute(name, connection -> connection.get(key));
}
```

ApiRequestContext is a custom request object here stored in the thread local.
Note that when this method returns null, the value is fetched from the db and put back into the cache, effectively refreshing the cache.